# Need help in regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to grep a particular value from each line shown below:

```
ABC_ROOT|/home/test/test_1/ABC/ABC-012/ABC04.16.103/lnx86
DEF_ROOT|/home/test/test_2/DEF/DEF192/DEF19.20.100/lnx86
GHI_ROOT|/home/test/test_3/GHI/GHI19.10.199/lnx86/tools.lnx86
JKL_ROOT|/home/test/test_4/JKL/JKL19.00.000/lnx86
ABC_ROOT|/home/test/test_1/ABC/ABC-012/ABC04.16.103/lnppc
DEF_ROOT|/home/test/test_2/DEF/DEF192/DEF19.20.100/lnppc
```

From the above lines, I want to grep the values that has version numbers
`ABC04.16.103`, `DEF19.20.100`, `GHI19.10.199`, `JKL19.00.000` for `lnx86` only.

I tried the below regex but it gives me result for both lnx86 and lnppc:

```
 /([A-Z]{3}\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{3})/
```

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/) all you need?

Comment: Yes can you please help.

Answer (score 4):

A good pattern includes everything you need to match the interesting data but also enough information to exclude the uninteresting data. Since you want only the lines with `lnx86`, make that part of your pattern. I've written this with the `/x` to spread out the pattern to make it easier to grok:

```
while( <DATA> ) {
    next unless m|
        /
        ( [A-Z]{3} \d{2} \.\d{2} \.\d{3} )   # $1
        /
        lnx86
        (?: / | \Z ) # another slash or end of string
        |x;

    print;
    }

__END__
BC_ROOT|/home/test/test_1/ABC/ABC-012/ABC04.16.103/lnx86
DEF_ROOT|/home/test/test_2/DEF/DEF192/DEF19.20.100/lnx86
GHI_ROOT|/home/test/test_3/GHI/GHI19.10.199/lnx86/tools.lnx86
JKL_ROOT|/home/test/test_4/JKL/JKL19.00.000/lnx86
ABC_ROOT|/home/test/test_1/ABC/ABC-012/ABC04.16.103/lnppc
DEF_ROOT|/home/test/test_2/DEF/DEF192/DEF19.20.100/lnppc
```

This selects the lines that you want:

```
BC_ROOT|/home/test/test_1/ABC/ABC-012/ABC04.16.103/lnx86
DEF_ROOT|/home/test/test_2/DEF/DEF192/DEF19.20.100/lnx86
GHI_ROOT|/home/test/test_3/GHI/GHI19.10.199/lnx86/tools.lnx86
JKL_ROOT|/home/test/test_4/JKL/JKL19.00.000/lnx86
```

You can generalize this a bit so you can choose a different tool later. Use `quotemeta` to ensure that nothing in the value is a regex meta-character (unless that's what you want):

```
my $tool = quotemeta( 'lnx86' );

while( <DATA> ) {
    next unless m|
        /
        ( [A-Z]{3} \d{2} \.\d{2} \.\d{3} )   # $1
        /
        $tool
        (?: / | \Z ) # another slash or end of string
        |x;

    print;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add positive lookahead at the end to make it match only lnx86 like this: `/([A-Z]{3}\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{3})(?=/lnx86)/`. This way it only match your pattern if it followed by the `/lnx86` string.

Comment: It gave the below error:

Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/([A-Z]{1,11}\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{3})( <-- HERE ?=/ at <filename>

Comment: @Pulkit you might have some copy paste error since the pattern has the matching `)`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you after?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

for (<DATA>) {                     # walk through data
    say $1 if m!([^/]+)/lnx86!;    # match pattern and output
}

__DATA__
ABC_ROOT|/home/test/test_1/ABC/ABC-012/ABC04.16.103/lnx86
DEF_ROOT|/home/test/test_2/DEF/DEF192/DEF19.20.100/lnx86
GHI_ROOT|/home/test/test_3/GHI/GHI19.10.199/lnx86/tools.lnx86
JKL_ROOT|/home/test/test_4/JKL/JKL19.00.000/lnx86
ABC_ROOT|/home/test/test_1/ABC/ABC-012/ABC04.16.103/lnppc
DEF_ROOT|/home/test/test_2/DEF/DEF192/DEF19.20.100/lnppc
```

Output

```
ABC04.16.103
DEF19.20.100
GHI19.10.199
JKL19.00.000
```